# Hello everyone.I want to import values into sql from access database but except previously added records from access

Tags: c#, .net

Getting values from my access database into `DataTable table`

```
string accessconst = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:/Program Files (x86)/BALLBACH/Database/Messdaten.mdb";
DataTable table = new DataTable();
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(accessconst))
{
    using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Messdaten", conn))
    {
        da.Fill(table);
    }
}
```

Getting values from my sql database into `DataTable tablesql`

```
string sqlconstr = "sqlconstr";
DataTable tablesql = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlconstr))
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT p1 FROM UMP", conn))
    {
        da.Fill(tablesql);
    }
}
```

Now I want to import the values into the sql db from the access db **except the previously added records** from the access db. How can I do this?

```
//HERE IS THE PROBLEM 
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionStr "))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO UMP VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        con.Open();

        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters["@p1"].Value = table.Rows[i][0];
            cmd.Parameters["@p2"].Value = table.Rows[i][1];
            cmd.Parameters["@p3"].Value = table.Rows[i][2];
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're asking, could you please be more specific?

Comment: Exactly as @AlexRiabov has noted before, we need some more information. All I see is a wall of code. Please add information about **what** you want to do, **expected output** and some test data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i would suggest is taking all access data and insert it into a temporary table.

then insert the data based on a left join, perform the insert.

your code would then look something like this...

```
    //data from access
    private void insertValues(DataTable table)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionStr "))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                createTable();
                //note changed the insert to tmp table.
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO UMP_TMP VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)";
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                con.Open();

                for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters["@p1"].Value = table.Rows[i][0];
                    cmd.Parameters["@p2"].Value = table.Rows[i][1];
                    cmd.Parameters["@p3"].Value = table.Rows[i][2];
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        break;
                    }
                }
                //merge the data from within sql server
                mergeTable();
                //drop the temporary table
                dropTable();
            }
        }
    }


    private void createTable(){
        issueStatement("create table UMP_TMP(p1 varchar(50), p2 varchar(50), p3 varchar(50));");
    }
    private void dropTable()
    {
        issueStatement("drop table UMP_TMP;");
    }
    private void mergeTable()
    {
        issueStatement("insert into UMP select ump_tmp.p1,ump_tmp.p2,ump_tmp.p3 from UMP_TMP left join UMP on UMP_TMP.p1 = UMP.P1 and UMP_TMP.p2 = UMP.P2 and UMP_TMP.p3 = UMP.P3 WHERE ump.p1 is null and ump.p2 is null and ump.p3 is null");
    }
    private void issueStatement(string command)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionStr "))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = command;
                //add error handling
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its nice idea and I tried but I am getting error **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ';'.'** to cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  I added error handling.

Comment: whoops sorry, my mistake updated the code above create table method was incorrect.

Comment: It works now. I was thinking compare 2 datatable and adding third datatable but better for me avoid DataTable.This is more useful.Thank you.

Comment: Great, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Kirk's response, your ultimate goal that solves the problem is to perform the left join operation on your two tables.  You will have needed to identified what columns on each table join the data, and what columns make a row unique.

You can do this in any of the 3 environments your working in a) Access, b) SQL, c) .NET.

I would recommend SQL, its the best at it. (plus your only transferring one set of data through the client (the access data))  So get all the data into SQL tables, and then execute a SQL stored procedure to do the left join and update the SQL data table.

You can work out the SQL work with just Management Studio, the queries etc.  Once you've built the stored procedure (and anything else you might need like views).  Your .NET code is then two simple parts, 1) upload the Access data 2) call the proc to merge it.

Final point, if your .net's client only purpose is this upload and merge, then you don't need it at all. SQL Servers SSIS can do all of this, and depending on the size of data involved might be the much better choice.